# In arm64 linux, why does cpu_context struct contain registers only from x19 up?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

In linux 5.10.0 code, in file arch/arm64/include/asm/processor.h
I see

```
struct cpu_context {
    unsigned long x19;
    unsigned long x20;
    unsigned long x21;
    unsigned long x22;
    unsigned long x23;
    unsigned long x24;
    unsigned long x25;
    unsigned long x26;
    unsigned long x27;
    unsigned long x28;
    unsigned long fp;
    unsigned long sp;
    unsigned long pc;
};
```

and this cpu_context is contained in thread_struct to store registers during the task swithcing.
I know for the function call, x19~ x28 are callee saved registers (the called function should preserve those registers and restore them before returning). But this hardware context switching is different from that and all the registers should be stored/restored. Why does this struct cpu_context have only registers from x19 and up?
(from the book "understanding the linux kernel 3rd edition, in p 105, about thread field, it says :

> Thus, each process descriptor includes a field called thread of type
> thread_struct, in which the kernel saves the hardware context whenever
> the process is being switched out. As we’ll see later, this data
> structure includes fields for most of the CPU registers, except the
> general-purpose registers such as eax, ebx, etc., which are stored in
> the Kernel Mode stack.

(though it's about x86 architecture))

Comment: From the kernel's perspective, the context switch is synchronous, isn't it?  It happens when kernel code explicitly calls `switch_to()` or whatever you may call it, so it follows the rules of a function call.  If preempting a user or kernel thread, that call may be happening from within a timer interrupt handler or something like that; but in that case, the interrupt handler itself will already have saved all the callee-saved registers.  (This is all inference, I didn't check the actual Linux code.)

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, the timer interrupt should have stored the registers. I later found the interrupt stores the pt_regs struct which contains all the registers, not just the callee saved ones. Thanks!